# Staying on same tab after a form is submitted in django and angular

Tags: python, angularjs, django

I've got a `boards.html` page and on that page I have 3 tabs (written with angular); Your Boards, Join Board, and Create Board.  Under the Join Board tab there is a join board button (which is a django function) that, when clicked, reloads the page so it goes back to the default Your Boards tab, I want it to stay on the Join Board tab.  Here is a bit of my code:

app.js TabController

```
app.controller('TabController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    this.tab = 1;
    this.setTab = function(newValue){
        this.tab = newValue;
    };

    this.isSet = function(tabName){
        return this.tab === tabName;
    };
    $http.get('/checklogin/').success(function(data) {
        console.log('Current User: ' + data.user_id);
        $scope.user = data;
        $scope.userid = data.user_id;
    }).error(function(data) {
        console.log('error: ' + data);
    });

}]);
```

views.py join_board function

```
def join_board(request, board):
    boardObj = Board.objects.get(board_name=board)
    if Profile.objects.filter(pk=request.user.profile.id, boards__pk=boardObj.id).exists():
        messages.error(request, 'Cannot join a board you are already a member of.')
    else:
        request.user.profile.boards.add(boardObj)
        boardMemberGroup = Group.objects.get(name=board + ' member')
        request.user.groups.add(boardMemberGroup)
    return boards(request)
```

relevant parts of boards.html

```
<section ng-controller="TabController as tab">
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
    <li ng-class="{ active:tab.isSet(1) }">
        <a href ng-click="tab.setTab(1)">Your Boards</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-class="{ active:tab.isSet(2) }">
        <a href ng-click="tab.setTab(2)">Join Board</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-class="{ active:tab.isSet(3) }">
        <a href ng-click="tab.setTab(3)">Create Board</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<!--  Your Boards Tab's Content  -->
<div ng-show="tab.isSet(1)">
    ...
</div>
<!--  Join Board Tab's Content  -->
<div ng-show="tab.isSet(2)">
    <h2>Boards you can join</h2>
    {% if found_entries %}
        {% for board in found_entries %}
            <h4> {{board.board_name}} </h4>
            <form action="/join/{{board.board_name}}/">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {% if board not in userBoards %}
                    <button id="join" type="submit" value="Delete"> {% trans "Join Board" %} </button>
                {% endif %}
            </form>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
            <h4> No Boards Found </h4>
    {% endif %}
</div>
</section>
```

I've tried

```
<form action="/join/{{board.board_name}}/" ng-class="tab.setTab(2)">
```

and that keeps it on the Join Boards tab after I click the join board button or refresh the page, but it also makes it so that I can't get to the other tabs.  I have read things about using ngCookie, but all of my tabs are on the same html page and all of those examples were for remembering a username or if someone is logged in, which is not relevant to my problem.  Also I am trying to avoid jQuery so I'd love to have any suggestions using just Angular and/or Django.

Comment: Are you open to building the form on the angular side? If you were to drop the django form and use an angular form with an ngClick directive you could just pass the data back to django as json without ever needing to reload the page. Perhaps you've already considered this though?

Comment: Yes that is something that I could do, the only thing is that it is much easier to interact with the database using Django.  I have found that Angular is easy to make things appear on the frontend but getting those changes to show up in the database is tricky @JwM

Answer (score 1):

Your whole page is reloading. That means you lose all the information you had on the page unless you store it somewhere. If you want to stay with Django forms I'd recommend adding query params to your angular routing, so that you can jump straight there when the page is loaded.

You're url would looks like `www.awesomeboards.com/boards?tab=2` then you'd look at your params on controller load and then switch to those params.

Otherwise you could look into [`django-angular`](https://github.com/jrief/django-angular), specifically the [section](http://django-angular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial-forms.html) on forms. I've not used it but it might help?

Comment: would i have to change my url pattern in `urls.py`?

Comment: @catherine it might be worth using angular js (perhaps ui-router)  to handle your URLs per app/project. That's what I find easiest. I'd you'd rather keep it all in `urls.py`, I won't be able to help.

Comment: Previously I tried adding hashes to the tabs so the url would look like `www.awesomeboards.com/boards/#tab2` and when I clicked different tabs it changed the url, but when I tried typing the url in directly with a different tab name, it wouldn't change what tab the page was on.  Would query params have the same issue?

Comment: You'll need to investigate that yourself for your setup. Ours was like `www.awesomeboards.com/boards/#site?tab=tab2 ` and the let us refresh. The quickest way to find out is to just try it.

Comment: Okay thanks for your suggestions!  I'd like to keep the urls in `urls.py` but I will explore more ways to incorporate angular and the query params

Comment: If this (at least partially) answered your question feel free to upvote and/or click the green tick.